# How to figure out if any of the N lines in 3D space intersect?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Let us assume that we have N lines in a three dimensional space. How can we figure out if any of these lines intersects any other line?

 
It would be great, if the problem was solved in terms of linear algebra. If it is not possible, why?

Comment: A single linear equation (i.e. a row of $Ax=b$) determines a 2D plane, not a line.

Comment: Indeed, it is true what you say. Thank you for pointing it out. I am thinking right now how to rephrase the question to get the same result (figuring out if any of the lines in 3D intersect).

Comment: You can use linear algebra to find the distance between any pair of lines: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13734/how-to-find-shortest-distance-between-two-skew-lines-in-3d. If the distance is zero, the lines intersect.

Comment: One good answer that can be used as a less algebraic solution can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2217845/559154).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, an intuitive explanation why it is not possible was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1026723/559154) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2546900/559154). Namely, if we have a three dimensional real space and no equation, the solution is whole space. Each succeeding equation tends to eliminate one "free" dimension out of the remaining ones.
For example, if we want a line, which is an one dimensional object, we need to eliminate two dimensions. This requires two equations, which represent two planes in the space. However, the planes should not be parallel.

The most algebraic answer so far comes from Gilbert Strang himself:

```
The case with N=2 lines makes it clear

Line 1     all points   a t + b   where a and b have 3 real components and t is a real number from -inf to +inf

Line 2      all points AT + B     where  A  and  B have 3 real components and  T is a real number ....

If those lines meet then there are numbers t and T such that   at + b = AT + B 

This is 3 eqns in 2 unknowns t and T    Create the vector x with components t and -T

   In matrix - vector form the 3 equations for x  are   [ a  A ] [ x ]     =  [B - b]

   With N lines you could check them 2 at a time -- or you could look for a better way
```

If the linear system has no solution, there is no intersection.

Answer (score 1):

According to the section about **the shortest line between two lines in 3D** [here](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/) 
: if there are $\mu_a$ and $\mu_b$ (the formulas are given) and $P_a(\mu_a)-P_b(\mu_b)=0$, then there is an intersection point. This is how you might want to find out, if two given lines in 3D intersect.

If you are given $N$ lines, then just make that test [as often as needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), which is $$\binom{N}{2}=N(N-1)/2$$ times.